# usb4java Error while sending message: USB error 1: Control transfer failed: Input/Output Error

Tags: usb, infrared, usb4java, write-error

I try to send a message with the usb4java api to a ir read and write element with this code:

```java
public static void sendData(DeviceHandle handle, int timeout) {
    
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(12);
    buffer.put(new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12});
    buffer.rewind();
    
    
    int transfered = LibUsb.controlTransfer(handle,
            (byte) (LibUsb.REQUEST_TYPE_CLASS | LibUsb.RECIPIENT_INTERFACE),
            (byte) 0x09, (short) 2, (short) 1, buffer, timeout);
    if (transfered < 0) {
        throw new LibUsbException("Control transfer failed", transfered);
    }
    System.out.println(transfered + " bytes sent");
    
}
```

But each time I try it, I get this error at `int = controlTransfer(handle, (LibUsb.REQUEST_TYPE_CLASS | RECIPIENT_INTERFACE), 0x09, (short) 2, (short) 1, buffer, timeout);`:

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.usb4java.LibUsbException: USB error 1: Control transfer failed: Input/Output Error
    at usb.reader.USBReader.sendData(USBReader.java:56)
    at usb.reader.USBReader.main(USBReader.java:42)
Java Result: 1
```

Maybe one of you have an idea how to fix this problem?

I really looking forward to your answer.

**EDIT:** I think I have to say that my operating system is Linux 64 bit in a VM VirtualBox on Windows 8.1 64 bit. (USB forwarding is activated; I already have accessed to the USB device)

Answer (score -1):

```
    int transfered = LibUsb.controlTransfer(
            handle,
            (byte) (LibUsb.REQUEST_TYPE_CLASS | LibUsb.RECIPIENT_INTERFACE),
            (byte) 0x09, //bmRequestType
            (short) 256, //wValue 
            (short) 0, //wIndex
            buffer, TIMEOUT);
```

**value wValue=256**

Comment: Hello, welcome to [so]. Code-only answers are discouraged 'round these parts, so please explain a little bit about your code along with your answer.

Comment: I suppose that the answer might be obvious from that had the user passed wValue as 256… but they didn't… and there's no explanation why that might cause a problem.